# I initialize DirectX object clearly, but it draw only black

Tags: c++, directx-11

I cording My DirectX FrameWork, I referencing Tutorial.
I think InitD3D() function is working well, 
but it can't clear RenderTargetView. only draw Black
though i set other colors. i try the debugging but i can't find anything.
I can't find what is problem. can i get answer?..

```
bool D3DClass::InitD3D(HWND hwnd, int width, int height)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
    D3D11_VIEWPORT m_viewPort;

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE(driverTypes);

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };
    UINT numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);

    // Create SwapChain
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = !FULL_SCREEN;

    featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

    // Create Device & Swa+pChain.
    for (UINT i = 0; i < numDriverTypes; i++)
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE t_driverType = driverTypes[i];

        hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
            NULL,              // Adapter (Graphic Card)
            t_driverType,      // Driver Type
            NULL,              // Driver Type Software. Usually set with 
            NULL.
            0,                 // Device Flag 
            featureLevels,     // FeatureLevel Array
            numFeatureLevels,  // FeatureLevel Count
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, // SDK Version
            &swapChainDesc,    // Swapchain Description Struct
            &m_swapChain,      // Created Swapchain Object
            &m_device,         // Created Device Object
            &featureLevel,     // Created FeatureLevel Information
            &m_deviceContext   // Create DeviceContext Object
        );

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            break;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Failed Create Device and Swapchain.", L"Opps!", 
    MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    // Get BackBuffer Pointer
    hr = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), 
    (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Failed Get Swapchain Buffer.", L"Opps!", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    hr = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, 
    &m_renderTargetView);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Failed Create Render Target View.", L"Opps!", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    // Release the backbuffer.
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    pBackBuffer = 0;

    m_deviceContext->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, NULL);

    // ViewPort
    m_viewPort.Width = (FLOAT)width;
    m_viewPort.Height = (FLOAT)height;
    m_viewPort.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    m_viewPort.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    m_viewPort.TopLeftX = 0;
    m_viewPort.TopLeftY = 0;
    m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewPort);    
    return true;
}
```

This function is clear the RenderTargetView.

```
void D3DClass::ClearScene()
{
    float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, color);
    m_swapChain->Present(0, 0);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `OMGetRenderTargets` should probably be `OMSetRenderTargets` because otherwise you are discarding target view that you've just created. Also you need to check return value of `m_swapChain->Present(0, 0);` and it is a good idea to put asserts to validate pointers before use.

Comment: Thank you for answer...!
i solve this problem with change OMGetRenderTargets
to OMSetRenderTargets.
Thank you very much again.